# Understanding bash echo

Tags: macos, bash, echo

I'm not understanding bash's `echo` command. Can you explain why `echo $a` just outputs a newline in the following?

```
MacbookAir1:so1 palfvin$ a='[]'
MacbookAir1:so1 palfvin$ echo $a

MacbookAir1:so1 palfvin$ echo "$a"
[]
MacbookAir1:so1 palfvin$ echo '[]'
[]
MacbookAir1:so1 palfvin$
```

I'd particularly appreciate a reference to some documentation explaining this.

The bash version is `GNU bash, version 3.2.51(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin13)`

Update: Output of examination of IFS after resetting per comment thread, is as follows:

```
MacbookAir1:~ palfvin$ echo "$IFS" | od -c
0000000       \t  \n  \n                                                
0000004
MacbookAir1:~ palfvin$ echo "$IFS" | od -h
0000000      0920    0a0a                                                
0000004
```

Comment: Which version of bash?

Comment: Whatever Mavericks has. How can I determine a specific version?

Comment: By asking it. `bash -version`

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I updated the question with the version information. For what it's worth, I tried `bash -v` before asking you how to get the version information.

Comment: just FYI, your first `echo $a` prints same output as others with my bash `4.2.45`

Comment: In light of the downvote (reason = not about programming), does anyone  know of a better SE site to be asking this question on?

Comment: Ignore them; they know not what they say.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having the `nullglob` shell option set can cause this. `[]` is a glob pattern that matches any of the characters between `[` and `]`, which is to say nothing. Normally, if the shell finds a pattern that doesn't match anything, it just leaves it alone; but with `nullglob` it's removed :

```
$ a='[]'
$ echo $a
[]
$ shopt -s nullglob
$ echo $a

$
```

From the [Filename Expansion section of the bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html):

> After word splitting, unless the -f option has been set (see The Set
>   Builtin), Bash scans each word for the characters ‘*’, ‘?’, and ‘[’.
>   If one of these characters appears, then the word is regarded as a
>   pattern, and replaced with an alphabetically sorted list of file names
>   matching the pattern. If no matching file names are found, and the
>   shell option nullglob is disabled, the word is left unchanged. If the
>   nullglob option is set, and no matches are found, the word is removed.

Comment: As shown in the chat (see comment trail after my answer), this is the key item. Peter had been working on a question where `shopt -s nullglob` was used.

Comment: +1 and Happy New Year to you and you, @JonathanLeffler!

Answer (score 1):

What's your `$IFS` set to?

When I set it to `IFS='[]'`, then I can reproduce your result (on a MacBook Pro running Mavericks 10.9.1 and using Bash 3.2.51(1)).  When IFS is set to spaces, the problem does not reproduce:

```
$ echo []
[]
$ x=[]
$ echo $x
[]
$ IFS='[]'
$ echo $x

$
```

Incidentally, `bash -v` invokes verbose mode; it echoes the shell script as it processes it.  You might still be in a sub-shell, which shouldn't matter much until you try to exit from it, when you'll find yourself in a long-forgotten parent shell instead of having a closed window.

Comment: How would I determine what `$IFS` is set to? `echo $IFS` gives me one newline.  `echo "$IFS"` gives me two newlines. :-)

Comment: That tells you it isn't set to `[]`.  You could use `echo "$IFS" | od -c` to see exactly what you've got -- space, tab, newline most probably.

Comment: Try starting a new shell in a new tab or terminal window and see what you get.  If that triggers the vanishing-brackets problem without you doing more than `echo []` in the window, then I'm going to be puzzled.

Comment: Oops, now I can't get back to my old `IFS` value, even after quitting Terminal. Will rebooting get me back to the old value (just to see what it was)?

Comment: `IFS=$' \t\n'` will set it back to what it was - or what it should have been.  But 'tis odd; setting `IFS` was one of the ways of breaking into systems long ago; shells stopped accepting inherited values to prevent that occurring.

Comment: Reboot done. It's still working. Sigh. Here's what it's showing for value of IFS: `MacbookAir1:~ palfvin$ echo "$IFS" | od -c
0000000       \t  \n  \n                                                
0000004
MacbookAir1:~ palfvin$ `

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44364/discussion-between-jonathan-leffler-and-peter-alfvin)